# T-SQL: Parsing String with Multiple delimiters

Tags: t-sql, parsing, split

I need to be able to query a SharePoint database for survey results.  The type of data I'm having problems with is a "Rating Scale" value.  So the data in each table column represents a whole group of sub-questions and their answers.

So the following is an example of what is found in ONE column:

**1.   Our function has defined how Availability is measured the hardware/software in Production;#3#2.   Availability threshold levels exist for our function (e.g., SLA's);#3#3.   Our function follows a defined process when there are threshold breaches;#4#4.   Our function collects and maintains Availability data;#4#5.   Comparative analysis helps identify trending with the Availability data;#4#6.   Operating Level Agreements (OLA's) guide our interaction with other internal teams;#4#**

The Questions end with a semi-colon and their answers are inside the two # signs.  So the answer to the first question is 3.

When I export the results of the survey it formats each question as a column header and the answer as the value in the cell below, which is ideal to get an average for each question, and would love to be able to replicate that from a SQL query.

But if I could get query results into two columns (Question, Answer)...I'd be thrilled with that.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks very much

Hank Stallings

*****ADDENDUM:**

This was my version of astander's solution...THANKS again!

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(  
        QuestionSource VARCHAR(50),  
        QA VARCHAR(5000)  
) 

DECLARE @ReturnTable TABLE( 
        QuestionSource VARCHAR(50), 
        Question VARCHAR(5000),  
        Answer int  
) 

DECLARE @XmlField XML, 
        @QuestionSource VARCHAR(50) 

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 
'Availability' AS QuestionSource,CONVERT(varchar(5000),ntext1) FROM UserData WHERE tp_ContentType = 'My Survey' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 
'Capacity' AS QuestionSource,CONVERT(varchar(5000),ntext2) FROM UserData WHERE tp_ContentType = 'My Survey' 

--SELECT * FROM @Table 

DECLARE Cur CURSOR FOR  
SELECT  QuestionSource, 
        CAST(Val AS XML) XmlVal  
FROM    (  
            SELECT  QuestionSource, 
            LEFT(Vals, LEN(Vals) - LEN('<option><q>')) Val  
            FROM    (  
                        SELECT  QuestionSource, 
                            '<option><q>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(QA,'&','&amp;'), ';#','</q><a>'), '#', '</a></option><option><q>') Vals  
                        FROM @Table 

                    ) sub  
        ) sub  

OPEN Cur  
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @QuestionSource,@XmlField  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO @ReturnTable  
    SELECT  @QuestionSource, 
            T.split.query('q').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') question,  
            T.split.query('a').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') answer  
    FROM    @XmlField.nodes('/option') T(split)  
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @QuestionSource,@XmlField  
END  

CLOSE Cur  
DEALLOCATE Cur  

SELECT * FROM @ReturnTable
```

Comment: I'd poke my eye out before using that cursor!  I'd use a set based approach like in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let see. I had to use a cursor, as this would probably have been better achieved from a programming language like C#, but here goes... Using Sql Server 2005, try the following. Let me know if you need any explanations.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        QuestionSource VARCHAR(50),
        QA VARCHAR(1000)
)

DECLARE @ReturnTable TABLE(
        QuestionSource VARCHAR(50),
        Question VARCHAR(1000),
        Answer VARCHAR(10)
)

DECLARE @XmlField XML,
        @QuestionSource VARCHAR(40)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT
'Availability','1. Our function has defined how Availability is measured the hardware/software in Production;#3#2. Availability threshold levels exist for our function (e.g., SLA''s);#3#3. Our function follows a defined process when there are threshold breaches;#4#4. Our function collects and maintains Availability data;#4#5. Comparative analysis helps identify trending with the Availability data;#4#6. Operating Level Agreements (OLA''s) guide our interaction with other internal teams;#4#'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT
'Capacity', '1. Our function has defined how Availability is measured the hardware/software in Production;#1#2. Availability threshold levels exist for our function (e.g., SLA''s);#2#3. Our function follows a defined process when there are threshold breaches;#3#4. Our function collects and maintains Availability data;#4#5. Comparative analysis helps identify trending with the Availability data;#5#6. Operating Level Agreements (OLA''s) guide our interaction with other internal teams;#6#'


DECLARE Cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT  QuestionSource,
        CAST(Val AS XML) XmlVal
FROM    (
            SELECT  QuestionSource,
                    LEFT(Vals, LEN(Vals) - LEN('<option><q>')) Val
            FROM    (
                        SELECT  QuestionSource,
                                '<option><q>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(QA, ';#','</q><a>'), '#', '</a></option><option><q>') Vals
                        FROM    @Table
                    ) sub
        ) sub

OPEN Cur
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @QuestionSource, @XmlField

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
    SELECT  @QuestionSource,
            T.split.query('q').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') question,
            T.split.query('a').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') answer
    FROM    @XmlField.nodes('/option') T(split)
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @QuestionSource, @XmlField
END

CLOSE Cur
DEALLOCATE Cur

SELECT  * 
FROM    @ReturnTable
```

Comment: astander - THANKS SO MUCH, this is perfect for my needs.

Comment: astander - Now, if I have multiple columns of these questions I can use UNION to pull in the questions from the other columns.  So one column represents "Availability", the next "Capacity", how can I add another column to determine which set of questions and answers the data is from?

Comment: astander - I've added my code to the bottom of my question. How can I edit it to include the QuestionSource column?

Comment: Where is the *QuestionSource* in your example?

Comment: Nevermind...I took a re-look at your code and I was able to fix my code.  Is it customary for me to post what I finally came up with here?

Comment: If none of the answer gave you **exactly** what you needed, then yes, you can, but keep it on your question, **dont create an answer to your own question X-)**

Answer (score 3):

You have to have a split function set up, but once you have it, try this cursor free solution:

[I prefer the number table approach to split a string in TSQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#tblnum)

For this method to work, you need to do this one time table setup:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number
    INTO Numbers
    FROM sys.objects s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2
ALTER TABLE Numbers ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)
```

Once the Numbers table is set up, create this split function, which WILL return empty strings and row numbers:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_ListToTableRows]
(
     @SplitOn  char(1)      --REQUIRED, the character to split the @List string on
    ,@List     varchar(8000)--REQUIRED, the list to split apart
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(

    ----------------
    --SINGLE QUERY-- --this WILL return empty rows
    ----------------
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number) AS RowNumber
            ,LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(ListValue, number+1, CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, ListValue, number+1)-number - 1))) AS ListValue
        FROM (
                 SELECT @SplitOn + @List + @SplitOn AS ListValue
             ) AS InnerQuery
            INNER JOIN Numbers n ON n.Number < LEN(InnerQuery.ListValue)
        WHERE SUBSTRING(ListValue, number, 1) = @SplitOn
);
GO
```

You can now easily split a CSV string into a table and join on it, NOTE this split function returns empty strings and row numbers:

```
select * from dbo.FN_ListToTableRows(',','1,2,3,,,4,5,6777,,,')
```

OUTPUT:

```
RowNumber            ListValue
-------------------- ------------
1                    1
2                    2
3                    3
4                    
5                    
6                    4
7                    5
8                    6777
9                    
10                   
11                   

(11 row(s) affected)
```

Your can now use a CROSS APPLY to split every row in your table like:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (RowID int, RowValue varchar(8000))
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (1,'1. Our function has defined how Availability is measured the hardware/software in Production;#3#2. Availability threshold levels exist for our function (e.g., SLA''s);#3#3. Our function follows a defined process when there are threshold breaches;#4#4. Our function collects and maintains Availability data;#4#5. Comparative analysis helps identify trending with the Availability data;#4#6. Operating Level Agreements (OLA''s) guide our interaction with other internal teams;#4#')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (2,'1. one;#1#2. two;#2#3. three;#3#')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (3,'1. aaa;#1#2. bbb;#2#3. ccc;#3#')

;WITH AllRows As
(
SELECT
    o.RowID,st.RowNumber,st.ListValue AS RowValue
    FROM @YourTable  o
        CROSS APPLY  dbo.FN_ListToTableRows('#',LEFT(o.RowValue,LEN(o.RowValue)-1)) AS st
)
SELECT
    a.RowID,a.RowValue AS Question, b.RowValue AS Answer
    FROM AllRows                  a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN   AllRows b ON a.RowID=b.RowID AND a.RowNumber+1=b.RowNumber
    WHERE a.RowNumber % 2 = 1
```

OUTPUT:

```
RowID       Question                                                                                        Answer
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------
1           1. Our function has defined how Availability is measured the hardware/software in Production;   3
1           2. Availability threshold levels exist for our function (e.g., SLA's);                          3
1           3. Our function follows a defined process when there are threshold breaches;                    4
1           4. Our function collects and maintains Availability data;                                       4
1           5. Comparative analysis helps identify trending with the Availability data;                     4
1           6. Operating Level Agreements (OLA's) guide our interaction with other internal teams;          4
2           1. one;                                                                                         1
2           2. two;                                                                                         2
2           3. three;                                                                                       3
3           1. aaa;                                                                                         1
3           2. bbb;                                                                                         2
3           3. ccc;                                                                                         3

(12 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response KM, I ended up going with stander's answer