# Search by nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this problem. In table I have column which is nvarcar type.
and row in this column is row1= 1;6 row2 = 12 row3 =6;5;67 etc...
I try to search this column. for example when i send 1 i try to get only row1. I use LIKE but in result set I get row1 and row2.

How can I achieved this, any help is appreciated.
Tnx...

Comment: can you paste your query. Make sure you are not using wild character "%" or "?".
your where clause should look like

WHERE columname LIKE '1'

Comment: Are the values stored in the column referencing other tables?  or are they just string values?  You may want to restructure the data, which would help your query

Comment: depending on the version of sql server, you could create a materialized indexed view of a CROSS APPLY using a split function on this table to get very fast selects, look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379973/t-sql-parsing-string-with-multiple-delimiters/2380312#2380312

Comment: Hi and tnx
Ok I will try this solution. Front end for usage of this sp is vb.net app. My goal is: I have list(of string) and for there I must get search result.
I will try to create some entity sql query to get this result
example.
for each r in lstSearch(of string)
dim res = entity - sql result/or function
add to new list
next
And here is my doubt. Should I use e-sql or ado.net to get this result, or try this your solution and everything put on sql side. Maybe only positive in this problem is this list(of string) have max. five numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not particulary elegant but this *get's the job done*.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Row NVARCHAR(32))

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('1;6')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('12')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('6;5;67')

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table
WHERE   Row = '1'
        OR Row LIKE '%;1'
        OR Row LIKE '1;%'
        OR Row LIKE '%;1;%'
```

### edit

follow up on your comment: this works in SQL Server 2005.

```
CREATE TABLE Analysis (Text1 NVARCHAR(32)) 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test] @Key as nvarchar AS 
SELECT  * 
FROM    dbo.Analysis
WHERE   Text1 = @Key 
        OR Text1 LIKE '%;'+ @Key
        OR Text1 LIKE @Key + ';%' 
        OR Text1 LIKE '%;' + @Key + ';%' 
GO

EXEC Test '1'
DROP PROCEDURE Test
DROP TABLE Analysis
```

Comment: hmmm when I put this in sp I can not get right result
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
 @Key as nvarchar
AS
SELECT * FROM  dbo.Analysis
where Text1 = @Key
OR Text1 LIKE '%;'+ @Key + ''
OR Text1 LIKE '' + @Key + ';%'
OR Text1 LIKE '%;' + @Key + ';%'

obviously i missing something here...

Answer (score 2):

**normalize your tables!**, storing multiple values in a single column will cause you grief as long as you use this design.  it might appear easier to store data this way, but as you are seeing it is difficult to query against this data, and the queries you do create will be awful and have no chance of using an index.

Comment: +1. Perhaps OP does not have control over the design of the tables but this should indeed be first thing on the agenda.

Comment: Yes I know, and I agree with all that but I can't noramalize this table and sure my main concern is performance issue with this. This table has appr. 15 000 records and also i Must query this table for example with value 1,3 and get result set :)

Answer (score 0):

You have four possibilities for where the key can be:

- It could be the entire key
- At the start
- In the middle
- At the end

Therefore, you have to select for each distinct possibility, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyColumn = @Key
   OR MyColumn LIKE @Key + ';%'
   OR MyColumn LIKE '%;' + @Key + ';%'
   OR MyColumn LIKE '%;' + @Key
```